# JSHint error when running Grunt with QUnit

Tags: javascript, qunit, gruntjs, jshint

I am running a Grunt build with JSHint and QUnit.
On my first test run I get the following:

```
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
Linting test/libs/qunit-1.11.0.js...ERROR
[L661:C22] W069: ['throws'] is better written in dot notation.
QUnit.raises = assert[ "throws" ];
[L1590:C33] W103: The '__proto__' property is deprecated.
      return obj.__proto__;

Warning: Task "jshint:files" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Besides editing the QUnit source code and using *--force*, what can I do with this?

Comment: Configure Grunt so you only run JSHint against your own files, rather than 3rd party files?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan :)

I'm new to Grunt (worked with Ant in the past). How would I do that?
`files: ['gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']`

Comment: That would run JSHint against any `.js` file in the *src* directory. If you don't put 3rd party files in there, it would work. Grunt accepts standard glob patterns so it won't be difficult to only include the correct files.

Comment: In this case, the test folder holds the QUnit files. What pattern should I use to not include them?

Comment: You should be able to use `!test/qunit/*.js`, or something along those lines. The `!` character is the important part. More info can be found in the [Grunt docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks) (see the "Globbing patterns" section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, assuming Grunt >0.4 and the grunt-contrib-jshint plugin, you can select specific files to run JSHint against. The JSHint Grunt plugin accepts standard glob patterns:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            'lib/**/*.js',
            'test/**/*.js'
        ]
    }
});
```

That example (from the JSHint Grunt plugin readme) will select any *.js* file within the *lib* and *test* directories (and their subdirectories), as well as the *Gruntfile.js* file. I would suggest moving 3rd party libraries out of your main *lib* directory. A common convention is to add a *vendor* directory for such scripts.

If the 3rd party scripts you rely upon are available via npm, you could also simply include them in your *package.json* file, and obviously leave the *node_modules* directory out of your Grunt config. It would then be up to your build process to move the necessary files into the right place within your app structure.